# Joda LocalDate compare if equal or before and after

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to compare joda LocalDate objects and check/compare if the date is between two dates.

Example:

```
LocalDate date = new LocalDate(2019, 2, 2);
LocalDate end = new LocalDate();
LocalDate start = end.minusYears(1);
```

Now, I want to check if `date` is between `start` and `end`.
Also, I want it to work like `gte` and `lte`... is before or equal and is after or equal.

I can only find `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isEqual`... but I cannot find `isBeforeOrEqual` and `isAfterOrEqual`.

Is there any utility that can work with joda LocalDate? Is there any efficient way to solve this?

I am thinking to check `isBefore` then `isEqual`, same with `isAfter` then `isEqual`... but I think it is quite long or inefficient.

```
private boolean isBeforeOrEqual(LocalDate date, LocalDate compareToDate) {
    if (date == null || compareToDate == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return compareToDate.isBefore(date) || compareToDate.isEqual(date);
}

private boolean isAfterOrEqual(LocalDate date, LocalDate compareToDate) {
    if (date == null || compareToDate == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return compareToDate.isAfter(date) || compareToDate.isEqual(date);
}
```

After Alex's comment below, I rewrite the methods `isBeforeOrEqual` and `isAfterOrEqual` and it is a lot shorter. Thanks a lot Alex.

```
private boolean isBeforeOrEqual(LocalDate date, LocalDate compareToDate) {
    if (date == null || compareToDate == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return !compareToDate.isAfter(date);
}

private boolean isAfterOrEqual(LocalDate date, LocalDate compareToDate) {
    if (date == null || compareToDate == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return !compareToDate.isBefore(date);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "before or equal" === "not after"

Comment: What Alex said, or you can `date.compareTo(compareToDate) >= 0` and such. Like with any `Comparable`.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah I did tried what Alex said and it is a lot shorter. for `isBeforeOrEqual` I just used `!date.isAfter(compareDate)`